# Angular ng-view - Failed to load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to load some HTML content with angular using "ng-view". I have everything setup, a module, controllers and my routes which looks like this:

```
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

// route for the home page
    .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
})

// route for the about page
.when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'components/about/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutController'
});
});
```

This is how the ng-view part looks like in my index.html:

```
            <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#/">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <div class="main">
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
```

My HTML files are located in seperate folders inside the folder "components", so the path should be correct. I'm also testing this on a server. But all i end up with is an error.

**This is what shows up on the console in Chrome:**

GET http://127.0.0.1:53283/components/about/about.html 404 (Not Found)
Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: components/about/about.html (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)

Anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you confirmed the file has been there in `/components/about/about.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`componentLoaderProvider`](https://angular.github.io/router/%24componentLoaderProvider) and config your app as follows:

```
.config (['$componentLoaderProvider', function ($componentLoaderProvider) {
    $componentLoaderProvider.setTemplateMapping(function (name) {
        return 'components/' + name + '/' + name + '.html';
    });
}])
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it with ng-view?

Comment: `ng-view` was changed to `ng-viewport`

Comment: @Griffith I think you are taking about Angular new router? He is using `ngRoute` which will never help help for his question